# How to iterate over cells in openpyxl using loops

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm learning openpyxl and I wanted to create a sheet with 2 cells, values 1 and 2, finding their sum, then adding the sum to the previous number, and so on (I think it might be called Gaussian summation).

```
ws["A1"] = 1
ws["A2"] = 2

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=1,max_col=1,min_row=1,max_row=10):
  for cell in row:
    iteration = 1
    value_1 = 1
    value_2 = 2
    if value_1 == 1 and value_2 == 2:
        value_3 = ws.cell(row = iteration, column=1, value= value_1).value + ws.cell(row = iteration + 1, column=1, value= value_2).value
        d = ws.cell(row = iteration + 2, column=1, value= value_3)
    else:
        value_3 = ws.cell(row = iteration, column=1, value= value_1).value + ws.cell(row = iteration + 1, column=1, value= value_2).value
        d = ws.cell(row = iteration + 2, column=1, value= value_3)
        iteration += 2
        value_1 = value_2
        value_2 = value_3`
```

The code prints 3 in A3, but then stops. I'm not sure exactly what's causing the problem in the code above, but I expected for the first if statement to do the summation of the initial given values, then the 2nd if statement to loop through the summation of the consecutive results and paste them into the next empty cells.

Comment: In your outer loop, you have `min_col=1,max_col=1`; is this correct?

Comment: So I used that syntax to indicate that I'm only using the first column and 10 rows, and it looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

`iteration`, which specifies which row to use to compute `value3`, is reset to 1 each iteration.

Comment: Oh, I see. That fixed the problem along with some minor adjustments. Thanks!